# PostgreSQL Negative Integer Overflow

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, postgresql-11

I was doing some tests on Postgres using the tinyint extension when I came across something surprising regarding its range. On typing `select -128::tinyint` it gave me an `ERROR: tinyint out of range` message which was not what I was expecting at all.

Assuming negative numbers should be 1 greater (or is it less) than the positive maximum (127 for single byte integers) I thought it was a bug with the extension, however on trying this with non-extended numbers I found exactly the same thing was happening.

`select -32768::smallint` -> out of range

`select -2147483648::integer` -> out of range

`select -9223372036854775808::bigint` -> out of range

Referring to the numeric data type documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html)
these numbers should all be possible - all negative numbers one less `-32767`, `-2147483647`, `-9223372036854775807` work correctly so I am curious as to why this is happening, or does this even happen with other peoples copies.

I tried using both postgresql 10 and postgresql 11 on a ubuntu 16.x desktop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *think* this is because the cast operator `::` has a higher precedence that the minus sign.

So `-32768::smallint` is executed as `-1 * 32768::smallint` which indeed is invalid.

Using parentheses fixes this: `(-32768)::smallint` or using the SQL standard `cast()` operator: `cast(-32768 as smallint)`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, inputting the number as a string e.g. `select '-32768'::smallint` will pass correctly also so I can only assume it would be the function ordering as you mentioned.